# onClick does not work when user clicks "back"

Tags: php, javascript

I have form elements that determine the action of the form like below.  This works great EXCEPT when they click the back button in their browser and it forgets the action.  What is the best way to fix this?

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="proptype" id="RESI" value="RESI" checked="checked" onClick="this.form.action='?frame=TEST&base=fc';" />
                Residential</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="proptype" id="LOTL" value="LOTL" onClick="this.form.action='?frame=TEST1&base=fc';" />
                Land and Lots</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of the (successful) radio button server side instead of changing the action dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    if($("#RESI").attr("checked")){
        form.action='?frame=TEST&base=fc';
    }else if($("#LOTL").attr("checked")){
        form.action='?frame=TEST1&base=fc';
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work?  Is it because the elements are radio and not checkbox?

Comment: In the future, please add a description to your post and not just code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a cookie that will remember the action which is pulled fresh each time the page is reloaded and then you should be able to create the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Use an onLoad javascript to pull the current states of all the form elements and calculate the correct action based on that